# Why can't you define a class or function in a non-enclosing scope?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++23

Consider

```
namespace M {
    void f();
    struct S;
}
namespace N {
    void M::f() {}
    struct M::S {};
}
```

This code is rejected by all compilers I tested, because `M::f` and `M::S` are only allowed to be defined in an enclosing scope. The standard also contains an [example](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning.general#example-2) that implies that a function may only be defined in an enclosing scope.

However, I can't figure out where in the standard to find the actual rule. In C++20 there was [class.pre]/3:

> If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, the *class-specifier* shall refer to a class that was previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the *nested-name-specifier* refers, or in an element of the inline namespace set (9.8.2) of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by a *using-declaration*),
> **and the *class-specifier* shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration**. In such cases, the *nested-name-specifier* of the *class-head-name* of the definition shall not begin with a *decltype-specifier*.

There was also a rule about member functions, but I couldn't find one for free functions. [P1787R6](https://wg21.link/P1787R6) removed the wording shown above, but the replacement wording doesn't seem to imply the same restriction. Here's what [class.pre] says in the C++23 draft:

> If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, the *class-specifier* shall not inhabit a class scope. If its *class-name* is an *identifier*, the *class-specifier* shall correspond to one or more declarations nominable in the class, class template, or namespace to which the *nested-name-specifier* refers; they shall all have the same target scope, and the target scope of the *class-specifier* is that scope. [...]

In the example above, the *nested-name-specifier* `M::` in the attempted definition of `M::S` denotes the namespace `M`, and `S` is nominable in `M` at this point because `S` was previously declared in `M`; [[basic.scope.scope]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#6).

Since I can't find any rule in the C++23 draft to forbid definitions in non-enclosing scopes, I might think that P1787R6 made it allowed. However, since compilers still don't accept this code, I think it's more likely that the rule still exists but is in some place that I've missed (or is phrased more subtly than it used to be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[expr.prim.id.qual]p2](https://wg21.link/expr.prim.id.qual#2):

> A declaration that uses a declarative *nested-name-specifier* shall be a friend declaration or inhabit a scope that contains the entity being redeclared or specialized.

Where your two redeclarations do not "inhabit a scope that contains the entity being redeclared or specialized". (Your original declarations inhabit the namespace scope `::M`, and the defining declarations inhabit `::N`, where `::N` does not contain `::M`).